# Good non-developer Android emulator?

Tags: android-emulator

Personally, I own an iPhone. However I would love to see the Android UI. I know a person who does have an Android, but never see it enough. I'd really love to have a good emulator that non-developers can use just to test out the Android UI. Is there any sort of apple app, Mac app, or non-developer tool out there to run the Android UI? Thanks!

Comment: Just Wondering, What's wrong with the SDK's emulator?

Comment: Maybe its too slow.

Answer (score 15):

Try Android x86 as a virtual machine on Virtual Box. this is by far the best working android I have seen...

1. It has the basic, default Android UI.
2. It is fully functional.
3. It works 4 times faster than my HTC Sensation

Android X86 ISO files: http://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/list

How to install it: http://dev.blogs.nuxeo.com/2011/10/speeding-up-the-android-emulator.html

Comment: Can you connect this to the Google or Amazon App Stores?

Comment: You can install Android Market, just google "android vending apk", download an apk, in console type "adb install filename.apk".  This is not certain to work without crashes since the market apk was designed to work with ARM processors, but if you'll be persistent enough you can find a stable enough market version.

Comment: KitKat version only works on Intel PC's, not AMD.

Answer (score 11):

Have you given the [Amazon Appstore](http://www.amazon.com/mobile-apps/b?ie=UTF8&node=2350149011)'s Test Drive feature a try? Super simple, runs in most browsers - simply find an app in the store for which Amazon has Test Drive available then click the big green Test Drive button (a [list of Test Drive apps](http://www.amazon.com/b/ref=amb_link_356762622_2?ie=UTF8&node=3071729011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=right-6&pf_rd_r=1194S98RV9WXD51QTRPK&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1332802942&pf_rd_i=2350149011) is here). Once you have a Test Drive session open click the home button on the bottom of the emulator to access the homescreen then voila, Android!

FWIW I personally don't think the SDK emulator is a bad choice even though it is developer-focused. Quick and easy instructions are at [How To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21831/how-to-test-drive-google-android-on-your-pc-without-buying-a-phone/) if you're interested.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to be a developer to install the Android SDK and run the emulator. Most of it's done through a GUI, too.

Answer (score 3):

[Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) is an accelerated emulator, which may let you get a better feel for the UI and graphics applications.

I believe it paravirtualizes graphics (OpenGL) calls, using the host's graphics processor to accelerate the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still searching the best solution would be [Bluestacks](http://bluestacks.com/). Its vey fluent and does not lag.

Comment: Lags on every computer I've installed.

Answer (score 1):

There's an iOS app called **Dreamboard** that allows you to use the Android UI on your iphone/ipod . It's just a launcher that changes the theme so as to give you a feel of how the Android UI looks like. Please note that, inorder to download this app, you should jailbreak your iOS device. I currently have this app on my ipod touch, downloaded from AppCake(which i downloaded from Cydia after jailbreaking my device)

Here's a video link: [Dreamboard in action](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=dreamboard%20for%20iphone&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC4QtwIwAg&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIKC8Bktgrw&ei=Hu4YT6r5CsSIrAeTiLHMDQ&usg=AFQjCNHZGLBxt-zzn93dBl-yP_U3wj4YDA&sig2=wyzr5mWllGk5YHKhaLxeFQ)

Hope this helps.